# Issue in Calling Stored Procedure from Shell Script

Tags: mysql, database, shell, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure `cleanRecords` in mysql database which modifies data in a table `dailyRecordLog`.

I am calling stored procedure `cleanRecords`after executing `MySQL DATA LOADER`.

The calls are initiated from a shell script `loadDataToDB.sh` as follows:

1. Shell script calls `MySQL DATA LOADER` to load data into `dailyRecordLog` table from a flat file. (records status are `pending cleanup`)
2. Shell script then calls `cleanRecords` stored procedure to clean records. 
   (records status are `cleanup success` / `cleanup failed`).

I am facing following issue:

- When I call `loadDataToDB.sh` records get loaded and final status is `cleanup success` but when I go to database, I see that records are actually not cleaned up. That is execution is partially successful.
- When I call `cleanRecords` from MySQL prompt on a data set already available in database, I see a completely successful execution.

I have verified this behavior multiple times and I have no clue why call initiation from shell script results in partial success.

Comment: would you show your shell script ?

Comment: It worked. It was a transaction issue. I added a commit before calling cleanRecords. It worked.